# WYSIWYG editor escapes image url

Tags: php, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm using CKeditor and I can't use images with it. When I'm creating a post/article with it add images and such, everything works. However after I submit the article into the database it escapes the url and overall the syntax which will result in no image shown when I try to view it.

This is the img syntax in the editor:

```
<img alt="logo" src="/images/image.png" style="width: 250px; height: 183px; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid;" />
```

This is after the insertion function runs:

```
<img alt=\"logo\" src=\"/images/image.png\" style=\"width: 200px; height: 147px; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid;\" />
```

You get the gist of it, it escapes all the necessities so it doesn't break the html. I did a few searches here and found something like `html_entity_decode`, which didn't work.

How can I properly "un-escape" the syntax so the image shows up properly?

PS: Here's the insertion and display script I use

```
public function insert () {
    $sql = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO Content (Title, Body, category) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $sql->bindParam(1, $_POST['title']);
        $sql->bindParam(2, $_POST['body']);
        $sql->bindParam(3, $_POST['category']);
        $sql->execute();
}

public function display ($id) {
    $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT Body FROM Content WHERE id='$id'");
    while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
        echo $row;
    }
}
```

I tried `html_entity_decode` in the display script like `$a = html_entity_decode($row['Body']);` and then echo that or assign the row to a variable and decode it then. Maybe I did it wrong, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added stripslashes($output) to the display function, like this:

```
public function display ($id) {
    $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT Body FROM Content WHERE id='$id'");
    while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
        //removes the extra slashes
        echo stripslashes($row); 
    }
}
```